# scrollview wont work on older OS versions

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview

When trying to display an image on my friend's phone, scrollview wont display it, instead, it will show a blank image. I can scroll up and down normally, and the button at the bottom also works, but the image just wont show up. His phone got android 4.1 and the program works fine on mine (6.0). Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imagem_teste" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/bt"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:backgroundTint="@color/viewfinder_laser"
android:text="Entendi"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the button's code that create and display the dialog:

```
btnSobre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);

            view.findViewById(R.id.bt).setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    alerta.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(TelaInicial.this);
            builder.setTitle("Sobre...");
            builder.setView(view);
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();

        }
    }
);
```

Could someone tell me why the image does not appear?

Comment: Android ScrollView works properly since its first release.

Comment: I did not understand! Does scroll view only work on newer versions of android, or does it work for all?

Comment: It works perfectly since Android 1.0 (never released to the public).

Comment: And you could tell me, then, why not be working with me?

Comment: Not without seeing your **complete** layout file.

Comment: But this is my entire layout, just missing the scroll view tags that did not appear. I inflate this layout in dialog and it works on my cell phone, but not on my friend's.

Comment: `missing the scroll view tags that did not appear` Then, it's **not complete**. I also fail to see the *xml prolog* in your layout file.

Comment: And now, did you see any problems?

Comment: Yes, of course. Your ScrollView is missing the `android:fillViewport="true"` attribute.

Comment: Did not work!!!

Comment: But the problem is not the ScrollView. Find out why the **image** is not displayed in the ImageView. Might be due to some restrictions in your manifest.

Comment: I got it. I just did this: android: hardwareAccelerated = "false". (in manifest)

Comment: And now it works. Now add your own answer and accept it. So this post will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just did this: android: hardwareAccelerated = "false". (in manifest)